# Whitney theorem for schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I feel more comfortable thinking of manifolds as the zero set of functions in $\mathbb{R}^N$, hence I look at abstract manifolds not as a generalization, but as a tool for constructing manifolds effortless, tanks to Whitney's theorem, e.g. I can realize the set of all lines in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a manifold, without going through the pain of constructing an explicit embedding.

I wonder if the same holds true for quasi-projective varieties. If a scheme is locally affine, can I say that it is a variety in $\mathbb{P}^N$? More precisely, if $(X,O_{X})$ is a ringed space that locally is isomorphic to $\text{Spec}(k[x_1,\dots, x_n]/I)$ for some ideal $I$ depending on the open set, then can I assert that $X$ is isomorphic to some variety $Y$ in $\mathbb{P}^N$? I mean variety for the open set of some projective variety, together with the sheaf structure associated with some ring $k[x_0,\dots,x_N]/J$, where $Y\subset Z(J)$.

The question is quite vague at many points, but I hope the answers will suggest counter-examples under some conditions and/or a list of additionals conditions under which part of the statement is true.

I appreciate any help.

PD: is the question fine here or it's better to post it in MO? I'm not confident of my knowledge of algebraic geometry.

Comment: All schemes, which are finite type over a field satisfies your hypothesis, but they are not necessarily quasi-projective and thus can not be embedded in a projective space as a locally closed subscheme.

Comment: Thank you Mohan, I didn't know what I wrote above was the definition of scheme of finite type over $K$, but due to my lack of understanding in algebraic geometry, could you point me a counter-example or a reference. What is the source of this "anomaly"? How to fix it?

Comment: Nonprojective schemes are not so easy to find. For example, every nonsingular 2-dimensional proper variety is projective. The simplest example in dimension 3 is explained in Appendix B of Hartshorne. I don't know what to say about the source of the anomaly, except that if you glue a bunch of affine things together, there does not seem to be a reason to expect the resulting scheme to have the right global structure (i.e. existence of an ample line bundle) to be embeddable in projective space.

Comment: Nefertiti, your reference is quite helpful, all of this helps me to understand.

Comment: Hartshorne gives a singular two-dimensional example in the exercises to II.7, I think. I'm not sure who we have to thank for that one.

Comment: I think it's exercise II.7.13. Running the risk of looking as a fool. Does the exercise imply that the variety cannot be realized as the open subset of a projective variety? Thanks.

Comment: @Hoot, OP: thanks for the reference! I didn't know that example was tucked away there. As for the question: this surface is proper, so its image under any morphism must be a closed subset. If it is also an open embedding, that means it would be an irreducible component, hence projective, a contradiction.